# Rails find_by_sql database type dependent

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

So in rails I use sqlite3 for development and mysql for production. Sqlite3 and mysql handle booleans differently ("t" or "f" in sqlite3 and true or false on mysql). Usually it's not a problem when I do a find because I can do this:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => ["viewed = ?", false])
```

And rails will insert the appropriate value depending on environment. But what if I want to do a find_by_sql in which I need a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck! #find_by_sql also performs database-agnostic string replacement when you pass it an array.

```
Comment.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM comments WHERE viewed = ?",  false])
```

Comment: ahhhh... I'm retarded, I guess I should have just tried that before posting this question.